# How to use Beholder drone?

Tags: x-rebirth

I try to use Drone to scan station.
When i select "Drone Scan", mission marker appears on one of shield generators. But when i move drone near them (17-20 m), nothing happens.

How this drones work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to press and hold "R" button when within 50m. It will scan and tell you to go to a few more targets for the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

I've had this problem too and it seems that the game's manual is wrong.

Pressing right click button doesn't seems to work when you are close to 30 meters.

Ive startet to push all the buttons of the keyboard and it seems that the "L" button does the work.

So, you have to stay close up to 30 meters of the scan point and then press the "L" button while looking to the scan point. After that it will start to make a scanning sound.

When that scan point is completely scanned, another one will show up.

Comment: Looks like you changed default controls. It require missile launch button, it is `R` in default settings.

Comment: Missile launch was bound to both L and R by default in my game. I was worried that I had a left and right missile launcher and that I would have to use both frequently, but both buttons just bind to the same action. So I figure both answer to this question (one says R, one says L) are both correct.

Answer (score 1):

It is the missile fire key. The default is L or R but if you have customized it, it is what ever you customized the missile key for.

Comment: I hate that they used the same key for missiles and scanning. Can't tell you how many missiles I've fired at stuff I was trying to scan because I was in the wrong mode. I just sell all my missiles now.